# Why is a class called an abstraction of an object?

Tags: java, object-oriented-analysis

I understand that a class is essentially a blueprint of an object, but the idea that a class is an 'abstraction' of an object is a little hard for me to wrap my head around... If anyone could tell me the real meaning of the statement: "A class is an abstraction of an object", I'd be really grateful.

My confusion is because this statement has been interpreted differently by different people...

Does 'abstraction' mean:

1. Dealing with the basics of a system, and not the deep intricacies of that system?

or does it mean that:

2. Only an abstract class can be considered an abstraction of an object?

Thanks in advance,
Abhigyan

Comment: An individual horse is a concrete physical creature. The concept of a horse is abstract - it doesn't exist physically but is an embodiment of what is common to all horses. Or, in other words, the class Horse is an abstraction of all individual horses.

Comment: Consider it a blueprint with concrete instances when that blueprint is materialized.

Comment: further to @sprinter 's comment, an abstract class cannot have an instance.  For example, the class `Animal` would be abstract because every time you wanted to make an instance of `Animal` you would have to indicate which `Animal` to instantiate, like a `Horse` instance (of type `Animal` but not generic)

Comment: @JeroenVannevel is a concrete horse an instance of a horse? Even if it is made of concrete?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A class is a description of everything that will be in a certain type of object. For instance, a car will have a steering wheel, seats, dashboard, etc and functions such as accelerating, stopping etc. Each individual car is a car object, but the conceptual car is analogous to the class.

> Dealing with the basics of a system, and not the deep intricacies of that system?

Somewhat, since a class does not usually describe exactly what goes into each field (for instance, the color of the steering wheel)

> Only an abstract class can be considered an abstraction of an object?

No, this is more general that the abstract keyword in Java.

Basically, a class is an abstraction because it describes what is created, whereas an object is created itself.

Answer (score 4):

A class can be instantiated into objects.  It captures the characteristics that are common to all these objects.

Answer (score 1):

A class defines fields & behavior (methods). It is instantiated into objects, which hold concrete values for those fields.

Abstraction as a term is used at many levels -- most commonly in regard of behavior. However in this regard it is being used of **value**.

We could state more clearly: A class is an abstraction across the possible values of its instances.

Example in pseudocode:

```
public class Cat {
    String name;
    String color;
}

object Cat ("Missy", "grey");
object Cat ("Whiskers", "orange");
object Cat ("Fluffy", "black");
```

As we see, class abstracts over values of its instances.